# Difference between recursive greatest common devisor and recursive pascal triangle

Tags: scala, recursion, greatest-common-divisor

Could someone explain me how these two recursive function are different from each other? 
I understand the mathematical approach of each one but I do not get why gcd() continues working until it finds the gcd but the pascal() stops after one round. 
Thanks.

**Greatest Common Deviser:**

```
def gcd(x: Int, y: Int): Int =
    if (y == 0) x else gcd(y, x % y)
```

**Pascal Triangle**

```
def pascal(c: Int, r: Int): Int = {
      if(c < 0 || r < 0 ||  c > r) 0
      else if(c == 0 || r == 0) 1
      else pascal(c-1, r-1) + pascal(c, r-1)

  }
```

Comment: What do you mean "stops after one round"? For example for `(3, 5)`, it needs 38 rounds. What do you mean "how these two functions are different"? They have in common a similar signature, they are written in the same language, they are both recursive, and that's about it. Everything else is different. The former function runs in linear time and is tail-recursive, the latter has two recursive calls -- that would be one difference. That's a really bad way to compute binomial coefficients, by the way.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I think I still have difficulties understanding recursion, the example that you provided can find the answer in one round of execution, pascal(3-1, 5-1) + pascal(3, 5-1) which gives 6+4=10, but I think it continues until it reaches to some point that it has to stop and return the answer, I can not find that point!, but in gcd() I can see if it reaches to 0 then the answer will be returned. The gcd() is an example from an online course that I am participating in it.

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "in one round of execution"? The "rounds" used by the recursive calls `pascal(3-1, 5-1)` and `pascal(3, 5-1)` don't count for some reason, or what? What's unclear with the base-case (or rather, pair of base cases) `if(c < 0 || r < 0 ||  c > r) 0
      else if(c == 0 || r == 0) 1`, how is it different from `if (y == 0) x` base case appearing in `gcd`?

Comment: I got my mistake in first round of execution, it should construct the whole triangle first and then return the answer but I don't understand how it returns it, the base-cases return 0 or 1 and don't return the actual value but in gcd() the base-case will result in returning x which is the actual value that is calculated by the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your `pascal`-method, augmented with a few indented outputs, to visualize in which order the calculation proceeds:

```
var currentIndentation = 0
def indenting[X](body: => X): X = {
  currentIndentation += 2
  val res = body
  currentIndentation -= 2
  res
}
def indentPrintln(s: String) = println(" " * currentIndentation + s)

def pascal(c: Int, r: Int): Int = {
  indentPrintln("pascal(%d, %d)".format(c, r))
  if(c < 0 || r < 0 ||  c > r) {
    indentPrintln("base case: return 0")
    0
  } else if(c == 0 || r == 0) {
    indentPrintln("base case: return 1")
    1
  } else indenting {
    val a = pascal(c-1, r-1)
    val b = pascal(c, r-1)
    val sum = a + b
    indentPrintln(
      "return sum pascal(%d, %d) + pascal(%d, %d) = %d + %d = %d"
      .format(c-1, r-1, c, r-1, a, b, sum)
    )
    sum
  }
}

println(pascal(3, 5))
```

For `(3, 5)`, it results in the following output:

```
pascal(3, 5)
  pascal(2, 4)
    pascal(1, 3)
      pascal(0, 2)
      base case: return 1
      pascal(1, 2)
        pascal(0, 1)
        base case: return 1
        pascal(1, 1)
          pascal(0, 0)
          base case: return 1
          pascal(1, 0)
          base case: return 0
          return sum pascal(0, 0) + pascal(1, 0) = 1 + 0 = 1
        return sum pascal(0, 1) + pascal(1, 1) = 1 + 1 = 2
      return sum pascal(0, 2) + pascal(1, 2) = 1 + 2 = 3
    pascal(2, 3)
      pascal(1, 2)
        pascal(0, 1)
        base case: return 1
        pascal(1, 1)
          pascal(0, 0)
          base case: return 1
          pascal(1, 0)
          base case: return 0
          return sum pascal(0, 0) + pascal(1, 0) = 1 + 0 = 1
        return sum pascal(0, 1) + pascal(1, 1) = 1 + 1 = 2
      pascal(2, 2)
        pascal(1, 1)
          pascal(0, 0)
          base case: return 1
          pascal(1, 0)
          base case: return 0
          return sum pascal(0, 0) + pascal(1, 0) = 1 + 0 = 1
        pascal(2, 1)
        base case: return 0
        return sum pascal(1, 1) + pascal(2, 1) = 1 + 0 = 1
      return sum pascal(1, 2) + pascal(2, 2) = 2 + 1 = 3
    return sum pascal(1, 3) + pascal(2, 3) = 3 + 3 = 6
  pascal(3, 4)
    pascal(2, 3)
      pascal(1, 2)
        pascal(0, 1)
        base case: return 1
        pascal(1, 1)
          pascal(0, 0)
          base case: return 1
          pascal(1, 0)
          base case: return 0
          return sum pascal(0, 0) + pascal(1, 0) = 1 + 0 = 1
        return sum pascal(0, 1) + pascal(1, 1) = 1 + 1 = 2
      pascal(2, 2)
        pascal(1, 1)
          pascal(0, 0)
          base case: return 1
          pascal(1, 0)
          base case: return 0
          return sum pascal(0, 0) + pascal(1, 0) = 1 + 0 = 1
        pascal(2, 1)
        base case: return 0
        return sum pascal(1, 1) + pascal(2, 1) = 1 + 0 = 1
      return sum pascal(1, 2) + pascal(2, 2) = 2 + 1 = 3
    pascal(3, 3)
      pascal(2, 2)
        pascal(1, 1)
          pascal(0, 0)
          base case: return 1
          pascal(1, 0)
          base case: return 0
          return sum pascal(0, 0) + pascal(1, 0) = 1 + 0 = 1
        pascal(2, 1)
        base case: return 0
        return sum pascal(1, 1) + pascal(2, 1) = 1 + 0 = 1
      pascal(3, 2)
      base case: return 0
      return sum pascal(2, 2) + pascal(3, 2) = 1 + 0 = 1
    return sum pascal(2, 3) + pascal(3, 3) = 3 + 1 = 4
  return sum pascal(2, 4) + pascal(3, 4) = 6 + 4 = 10
10
```

Hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: Really appreciate what you provided, it helped me figuring out how the recursive function works and I read couple of notes on the net to find out how to think when I want to write a recursive algorithm.

Comment: @MORTI `for (i <- 1 to 5) { /* read a random article about recursive algorithms for half an hour */; /* Try to implement some basic recursive algorithm (gcd's, all kind of combinatoric formulas, mapping lists, traversing trees, merge-sort etc) for an hour*/ }`. Recursion is fundamental, and there is essentially nothing else that you could use to explain how it works. There is no shortcut. Just try to understand as many examples as you can, it will click eventually.

Comment: The problem is that Scala syntax and functional programming are both new to me so I have to put more effort on them to understand complicated topic like recursion, by the way, like your last sentence: "it will click eventually" :D , Thanks a lot again.